# How can I filter events by event_type?

Tags: feature-request, api-v2.2, events

I am using [the `/events` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/events) in the API and it returns all events from Stack Overflow.

But I want to filter based on `event_type`. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no method to filter events by `event_type`.

For now, just load all the events and filter through the `event_type` values afterwards.  Since the `/events` route only covers the last 15 minutes, it will only take 2 to 10 pages to get all the unfiltered results on Stack Overflow (the busiest site).

---

However, your options increase depending on what you want to filter for.
If you are interested in the `question_posted`, `answer_posted`, `comment_posted`, or `user_created` event types; merely call the:

- [/questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions)
- [/answers](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers)
- [/comments](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments)
- [/users](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users)

route(s), respectively, but:

1. Sort by `creation`, `desc`.
2. Specify a `fromdate` that is 15 minutes in the past. (`fromdate` is really a date plus time, to the nearest second.)

---

Unfortunately, if you want **to filter for `post_edited` events**, you are out of luck.  There's not really a good way to work around that (yet).